# Spring MVC Redirect. Model and Forms Clearing

Tags: spring, forms, validation, post, get

Let's say I have a web form and whenever the form is submitted it undergoes validation.

If there is an error I redirect it to the same page and uses **RedirectAttributes** to maintain the form values for resubmission.
Else, it submits to the next page successfully.

Problem: 
(1) Whenever I go back, or revisit the same form url, it always retains the submitted inputs 
(2) Trying to submit new values, it changes (updates) the previous data submitted.
(3) After a successful submission I want it to be cleared as a new form object.

So far here is my Controller Code:

***GET***

```
@RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String setForm(Model model, HttpSession session){
Object o;
if(!model.containsAttribute("object")){
    model.addAttribute("object", new Object());
}
else{
    l= (Object)modelasMap().get("object");
}
return "app/formUrl";
}
```

While in my ***POST***

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String formSubmit(@ModelAttribute("object" Object object, 
final BindingResult result, HttpSession session, 
SessionStatus status, RedirectAttributes attr){

//DO some object manipulation code here

//validation code
if(result.hasErrors()){
     attr.addFlashAttribute(org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.object", result);
     attr.addFlashAttribute("object", object);
return "redirect:/formUrl";
}
else{
//save form inputs here
}
}
return "redirect:successPage";
}
```

I'm really confused as to why its not returning a new cleared form when I have set a condition `if(!model.containsAttribute("object"))` in my GET.

I hope someone could explain to me what seems to be the problem. Thanks in advance!

***EDIT:***

Adding `<mvc:annotation-driven ignore-default-model-on-redirect = "true"/>` gives me the error:

`cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect' is not allowed to appear in element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.`

Same error if I use `ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect`

Additional information - I am on Maven build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found the answer. I replaced the whole ***GET*** method with a ModelAndView with respective parameters (url, model, new Object()).

And under 'if(result.hasErrors())' return should be a forwarding not a redirection url.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting `ignore-default-model-on-redirect` attribute to true in your servlet configuration?  As follows:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true" />
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html#setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect-boolean-):

> By default, the content of the "default" model is used both during rendering and redirect scenarios. Alternatively
> a controller method can declare a RedirectAttributes argument and use it to provide attributes for a redirect.
> Setting this flag to true ensures the "default" model is never used in a redirect scenario even if a
> RedirectAttributes argument is not declared. Setting it to false means the "default" model may be used in a
> redirect if the controller method doesn't declare a RedirectAttributes argument. The default setting is false but
> new applications should consider setting it to true.

Comment: using this approach, I'm going to encounter a probem since I am using a Maven build, is this the only way?

Comment: You could try using the ``RedirectAttributes`` argument described above. Here is the link to the java doc with an example: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Comment: Adding <mvc:annotation-driven ignore-default-model-on-redirect = "true"/> gives me the error:

cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect' is not allowed to appear in element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.